# Backbone.js 0.9.10 Collection fetch JSONP

Tags: backbone.js

```
var COLLECTION = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: "example.com",
    sync: function(method, model, options){
        params = _.extend({
            type: "get",
            url: this.url,
            async: false,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonpCallback : "jsonp_callback",
        },options);

        return $.ajax(params);
    },
    parse:function(response){
        console.log(response);
        return response;
    }
});
var a = new COLLECTION();
var b = new COLLECTION();
$.when(a.fetch(),b.fetch()).done(function(){ console.log('done'); });
```

I have two questions：

1. In sync function, $.ajax(params) response `TypeError: a["reset"] is not a function` @0.9.10
2. Use multiple collection.fetch sometimes happen `a.fetch() or b.fetch() response parse error`

Thanks!!